# How can I apply a matrix 2*2 to binary digits?

Tags: functions, binary

I want to apply a matrix 2*2 to a binary digits.
For example, D and E are two matrices that they apply to a 1 and 0.
D --> 1 & E --> 0
binary digits: (1011) --> D.E.D.D

Comment: Unless I'm reading you wrong, you can use `IntegerString[]` and `StringReplace[]` to do what you want. Otherwise, please edit your question to clarify. If you have to, you can write in your native language instead of English.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IntegerDigits` to produce binary digits of some base 10 integer, 11 in the following example.

```
IntegerDigits[11,2]
(* {1,0,1,1} *)
```

Then use rules to convert each digit to the corresponding matrix, and form the dot product.

```
Apply[Dot,IntegerDigits[11,2]/.{0->e,1->d}]
```

Alternatively, select the appropriate matrix from a list.

```
Apply[Dot,{e,d}[[IntegerDigits[11,2]+1]]]
```